# Read JSON from GoogleApis

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I'm new to android and I'm having some trouble trying to read this JSON from :

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=portugal&sensor=true

```
 {
"results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Portugal",
           "short_name" : "PT",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Portugal",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 42.15420480,
              "lng" : -6.19020910
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 32.403740,
              "lng" : -31.2751580
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 39.39987199999999,
           "lng" : -8.2244540
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 42.15420480,
              "lng" : -6.19020910
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 36.96017720,
              "lng" : -9.51711070
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
  }
  ],
  "status" : "OK"
}
```

Can anybody point me to some library or some code to get me started? :D

Ty in advance

***EDIT***

Is is possible to use this result and show the actual location in google maps in an Activity?

Comment: what is current issue reading json from google api or you are not able to parse it?

Comment: i'm a newbie and im not able to parse it xD

Comment: See ``org.json`` package within Android SDK. There's classes for parsing and accessing JSON data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the parsing problem. You can use [google http java client](http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/). There are some example in [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

results[0].address_components[0].long_name will output Portugal

results[0].geometry.location.lat will output 39.39987199999999

etc...

you can use the lat and lng to center the map on that location using map.setCenter(latlng:LatLng)